# Magento 2 jQuery Modal Not displaying in center

Tags: magento2, jquery, popup

I'm new to Magento 2. For homepage popup i have added below code

```
<div id="popup-modal">
        Test Data
</div>

<script>
        require(['jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'], function ($, modal) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));

            $('#popup-modal').modal('openModal');
            $('.modal-footer').hide();
        }
        );
</script>
```

It's not showing in center, as well how to set height & width of modal. Can we make auto as per content?
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just change or overwrite following style

```
.modal-popup._show .modal-inner-wrap {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: auto;
    top:50%;
}
```